# For better battery backup whether we have to start charge the laptop when battery about to drain?

Tags: laptop, battery, battery-life

I  recently purchased a laptop ,I have  get suggestions from so many people that we should start charging laptop when battery is about to drain and the reason I am getting is battery will last for years if i do that. Is it true.?

Comment: I have a much better answer for the subjective along with the most recent post - am a subject expert. How should I deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

Lithium Ion batteries much appreciate a full cycle - drain to the last drop then fully recharge, as the predicted life-time is a function of this state.

This practice might work for a few select applications such as cell phones, but in laptops the typical usage is actually works AGAINST this battery chemistry (as soon as you plug in the battery starts to charge!)

I would not worry about how long the battery is functional - I would more worry about if there is a replacement. For about two decades now I buy, and I recommend all my friends and family to buy, laptops alongside with one maximum-capacity replacement battery. The battery-replacement business seems to have improved over the years, but I still like to have one installed in the laptop, and I carry the other ready to be charged.

If this is a new laptop you bought, and you are able to afford it you probably should buy one extra battery as well.

Comment: The deeper you discharge the cells the less the self-discharge rate becomes, so once you reach the minimum level the only remaining factor is going to be the rated shelf-life of the chemistry - for Lithium Ions it is about 5 years since chemically it is a very active mix - it provides much potential but little stability. You could over-drain an assembly and loose the battery, but only by your own purpose and design and not by regular use.

Answer (score 1):

If You notice Battery would get drain once it reached 5-10% level  since it would be discharging some amount even it is not connected to the laptop or if the laptop is  turn off so  it is not proper to wait until it get drained completely.

The reason is that if the battery is unused for months without any charge then it would lose the ability to store charge.

Comment: This is not correct, Lithium Ion batteries do not self-discharge at the rate, to the point of no return, in the length of time you describe. It is also very 'proper' to drain them as deep as the protection/charging circuit of the cell assembly allows it - as the matter of fact it allows the cell assembly to retain the most charge it may possibly hold. Number of charging cycles are limited by chemistry, but the amount of charge the battery is able to hold is kept optimal with deep cycles - that is, drain to the last drop until the protection circuit shuts down, then fully recharge.